# Read raw data from wired mouse

Tags: cmd

I need to obtain raw data from a USB wired optical mouse(x and y axis motion coordinates). Is there a way to do this from Windows command prompt? I have the windows driver kit installed. But I am not sure how to proceed to obtain the raw values.Any suggestions?

Comment: "Windows command prompt" can run an exe (which in turn can do many thins including running a script). Does the windows driver kit have any exe that will let you do this? Probably not. So you need to write a console application (that can run in a prompt) that will do it for you.

Comment: @Nick.McDermaid The driver kit has a .exe file, but the file doesn't run

Comment: Have you done any programming before? What purpose do you have for getting 'raw' data from a mouse (wired or wireless it's irrelevant - coordinates are coordinates). Why does it need to be in a command prompt? Here's an easy way of doing it but is not in a command prompt. https://www.w3schools.com/jsref/tryit.asp?filename=tryjsref_event_mouse_clientxy2

Comment: With regards to the command  line I suspect this is a case of the XY problem http://mywiki.wooledge.org/XyProblem

Comment: @Nick.McDermaid The purpose of doing it in the command prompt is to run it as an application

Comment: Generally users don't use applications through the command prompt. What does this final application look like? Is it a windows application or a web application?

Comment: Windows application

Comment: Did you read the XY link that I posted? It's quite possible that getting coordinates out of a mouse into a cmd shell window is completely irrelevant to your real requirement. Generally if you build a windows application (depending on the language and library you use), all mouse handling is taken care of. You don't need to worry about this stuff unless you have a specific requirement.

Comment: So what you need to do is close stack overflow, download a free visual studio. One like this: https://www.visualstudio.com/vs/visual-studio-express/ and follow a tutorial and learn about making an application. When you have an actual question come back and ask it.